# MySQL query optimization - add a new column with the max value of the group. The value should be repeated for the entire group

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, max, aggregate-functions

I have a mysql table with the following columns- Date, country, YEAR, MONTH, supercategory, class, corp_manufacturer, brand, license,item_description,amount, units, arp.

Total number of records = 7.1 million

Now i want to add a new column which shows the max value of arp for the group (country, YEAR, MONTH, supercategory, class, corp_manufacturer, brand, license,item_description). This max value has to repeated for the all the members in the group.

I have tried the following 2 methods. Both works but both of them takes a long time to update the data more than 2 hrs.

I'm looking for any better solutions that can do this faster. Please help.

Method 1- update the table from subquery

```
UPDATE table a
INNER JOIN (SELECT Country,YEAR, MONTH, supercategory, class, corp_manufacturer, brand, license, item_description, MAX(arp) AS max_arp FROM table GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) b  

on a.country = b.country AND a.year = b.year AND a.month=b.month AND a.supercategory=b.supercategory AND a.class=b.class AND a.corp_manufacturer=b.corp_manufacturer AND a.brand=b.brand AND a.license=b.license AND a.item_description = b.item_description

SET a.max_arp= b.max_arp
```

Method 2 - create temp tables with indexes and join them in to a new table

```
INSERT INTO  temp1
(SELECT Country,YEAR, MONTH, supercategory, class, corp_manufacturer, brand, license, item_description, MAX(arp) AS max_arp 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

INSERT IGNORE INTO  temp2
SELECT a.*,b.max_arp AS SRP FROM  table  a  JOIN  temp1 b
ON a.country = b.country AND a.year = b.year AND a.month=b.month AND a.supercategory=b.supercategory AND a.class=b.class AND a.corp_manufacturer=b.corp_manufacturer 
    AND a.brand=b.brand AND a.license=b.license AND a.item_description = b.item_description;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compute the group count with a window function. That said, why create a column when you can just use a view:

```
create myview v as
select t.*,
    max(arp) over(partition by 
        country, 
        year, 
        month, 
        supercategory, 
        class, 
        corp_manufacturer, 
        brand, 
        license,
        item_description
    ) max_arp
from mytable t
```

With this technique, you get an always up-to-date perspective at your data, for 0 maintenance costs. Note that this requires MySQL 8.0.

*If* you insist on storing the information, then in MySQL I would recommend the update/join syntax. Assuming that your table has a primary key called `id`:

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select id,
        max(arp) over(partition by 
            country, 
            year, 
            month, 
            supercategory, 
            class, 
            corp_manufacturer, 
            brand, 
            license,
            item_description
        ) max_arp
    from mytable t
) x on x.id = t.id
set t.max_arp = x.max_arp
```

Comment: The reason I can't do this as a view is because this is not my final table. I have other transformation steps after this. Infact i have to do a similar max per group step again for a different column. 
Also if I save this result as view and use that view in the next steps of transforamtions, it takes the same amount of time (2.5-3 hrs)

The second solution - can I use that with out Id field? Since I  do not have id, i'm using my first method where i take all the columns in sub query and use them in join condition.

Comment: That _will_ take a long time.  So the "solution" is to avoid doing it.  Views and Overs do not help.

Comment: I will give the view option a try and update here. Thank you

Comment: Creating views is working for me. But sometimes it is unstable. It just takes forever to load. I kill the process and run it  again and then it would succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will better if your table has the following two indexes :

1. Index for field `arp`.
2. Index for fields `Country, YEAR, MONTH, supercategory, class, corp_manufacturer, brand, license, item_description`.

After that you can use what ever you want.

For using temporary table it will be faster if `temp1` has the same Index `Country, YEAR, MONTH, ....` as in your table. The second part of your query will be:

```sql
    UPDATE table a, temp1 b ON 
    a.country = b.country AND a.year = b.year AND a.month=b.month AND  
    a.supercategory=b.supercategory AND a.class=b.class AND  
    a.corp_manufacturer=b.corp_manufacturer AND a.brand=b.brand AND  
    a.license=b.license AND a.item_description = b.item_description
        
    SET a.max_arp= b.max_arp;
```

Comment: ARP is a number column. Average retail price. So I cant have index on that. But i have created indexes on the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with the desired arp values:

```
CREATE TABLE the_groups (
    PRIMARY KEY (Country,YEAR, MONTH, supercategory,
                 class, corp_manufacturer,
                 brand, license, item_description)
    ) AS
  SELECT  Country,YEAR, MONTH, supercategory,
          class, corp_manufacturer,
          brand, license, item_description,
          MAX(arp) AS max_arp
    FROM  table
    GROUP BY  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
```

(That is *much* faster than `UPDATE`.)

If necessary, you can keep `the_groups`, but you would need to maintain it whenever `tables` is modified.

Meanwhile, you can have the effect of what you asked for via

```
CREATE VIEW table_plus_maxarp AS
    SELECT a.*, b.max_arp
        FROM `table` AS a
        JOIN `the_groups` AS b
            USING (Country,YEAR, MONTH, supercategory,
                   class, corp_manufacturer,
                   brand, license, item_description)
           ;
```

Comment: I havent created a primary key but i have indexes on the other column. I will try the primary key method